# Click after Mouse Over stopped working

Tags: robotframework

Robot Framework. Firefox (latest).

Simple scenario: menu bar with expanding menus opening on mouse hover event. Need to hover over the menu element and then click on the submenu.

I used simple path: 'Mouse Over ', then 'Click Element '.

Everything worked fine for more than a year. But a week ago or so it just stopped.

I tried adding 'Wait Until Element Is Visible ' between the two steps. Tried the old Chrome trick adding the 'Focus '. Nothing seems to work.

So actually I have two questions:
1. Am I the only one experiencing this?
2. How to fix this as menu navigation has to be used in some cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would need more informations about the library you use (I assume robotframework-selenium2library) and the error message you get, but I guess you are hitting are firefox version incompatibility. Note that Selenium lib sometimes needs to be updated when new version of browsers appear. Last time I checked, the last version of Firefox that is supported by robotframework-selenium2library is 31. So, would it be possible that you updated firefox recently? If so, try to install an older version.

Comment: Yes, the Firefox was updated. Will try to downgrade (and I am almost certain it'll fix the issue).